# Connect to Core MVC application data context from Core console application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core, console-application

I have an issue that requires me create a new Core Console application in the same project as my Core 2.0 MVC Web Application. In my MVC application I can easily connect to my database via the system data context. However when I try to connect using the same code in my console application, the query will return that the db is null. I have referenced my MVC project in the console application but no luck. Thanks in advance. Please see below:

**Data Context**

```
public class SystemDataContext : DbContext
{
    public SystemDataContext(DbContextOptions<SystemDataContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Facility> Facility { get; set; }
}
```

**MVC - Works**

```
public class FacilityService
{
    private SystemDataContext db;
    public FacilityService(SystemDataContext dataBase)
    {
        db = dataBase;
    }

    public List<Facility> GetFacilities()
    {
        var facilities = db.Facility.ToList();
        return facilities;
    }
}
```

**Console Application - Returns db null error**

```
public class Program
{
    private SystemDataContext db;
    public Program(SystemDataContext dataBase)
    {
        db = dataBase;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var facilities = db.Facility.ToList();

        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Comment: MVC application is working as you may have setup dependency injection. Where in console, you should create a new instance or setup the dependency injection.

Comment: you should not want to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because MVC Core is configuring the dependency injection properly, as opposite to the console application.

In your console application, you may instantiate your `DbContext` manually using this:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
              .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
              .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

var configuration = builder.Build();
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SystemDataContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnection("DefaultConnection"));
var db = new SystemDataContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
```

You should have the `appsettings.json` with the connection strings properly in your console application as well.

> It would be also a good idea to put your `DbContext` in a class library project, and reference it from both the MVC and Console apps.